# Safari caching my AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari

I want one of my pages to fire a javascript AJAX call every time the user loads the page, even if he is coming back to a page in the browser's history. So I've put this function in my jsp (I am using jQuery Mobile):

```
$(document).on(
        "pageinit",
        "#base-layout",
        function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            myFunction(urlEndpoint);   
        });
```

With only this code, and the javascript function:

```
function myFunction(url) {

    var currentTime = new Date();
    var n = currentTime.getTime();

    var epUrl = url + "?nocache" + n;

    $.ajax({
        url : epUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        method: "post",
        headers : { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        cache:false,
    }).done(function(data) {
        //do something
    });
}
```

I managed to get Chrome, Firefox and IE to actually fire the ajax call even when pressing the back button. But I can't manage to get Safari to show this behavior. No matter what I try, it's never going through my server side function.

As you can see, I tried disabling cache for the ajax call, and changing the endpoint url by appendind the current time, to no effect. I even tried to put

```
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```

on my controller method, but it didn't work either. I can't get Safari to call this function when coming back to a page in history.

Comment: On Windows, and on the iPhone (iOS 7) and Mac

Comment: Try hooking into the `popstate` event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/popstate

Comment: It worked with the popstate event. Thanks.